# Searching products using details.name and details.value using the Best Buy API

Tags: best-buy-api

The Best Buy Search allows to search products specifying  a criterion on details.name and details.value fields.

```
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(details.name="Processor Speed" & details.value="2.4Ghz")?apiKey=YOURKEY
```

However details is a collection. The query above actually returns all products has a detail entry named "processor" and a detail entry whose value is "2.4Ghz" but not necessarily in the same details entry. Is there a way to create a query that will return only products for which those value and name are for the same details entry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this unless the particular detail you are interested in has been exposed as a top level attribute (processor speed has not). To accomplish this you will need to run your query as you have described, and then comb through the results and remove the irrelevant products in your own code.